# Comparing maintenance energy costs of plant biomass vs bacterial biomass

Tags: botany, mitochondria, energy-metabolism

Im interested if anyone has an idea if this research has been done or how you would approach it.

What is the energetic maintenance cost of (e.g) 2kg of some given bacterial cells vs 2 kg of a plant (like soybean).

Bacteria have less DNA to maintain per cell, less organelles, they dont fight gravity (not sure if this one matters), and probably have less active transport mechanisms. I guess the amount of energy they need just to maintain their biomass is much lower than a plant.

Comment: I did find this paper: 
It shows the values normalized to nitrogen content prokaryotes ~150W/kgN vs plants 200 to 400W/kg N. But the study seem oh so complicated to me https://www.pnas.org/content/105/44/16994#T1